# Proving $\mathbb C[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2+1\rangle,\mathbb R[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2+1\rangle$ are integral domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, integral-domain

As a homework assignment,

> I need to prove that $\mathbb C[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2+1\rangle$ and $\mathbb R[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2+1\rangle$ are integral domains.

I have no idea how to approach problems like this. We're allowed to use the fact that for any field, $\mathbb F[x,y]/ \left\langle xy+b \right\rangle $ is an integral domain iff $b\neq 0$.

Here are some thoughts: If $x^2+y^2+1$ is irreducible then it generates a prime ideals and we're done. Otherwise, since each of the polynomials rings is a UFD, we may factor it into irreducibles. Then I thought of using the chinese remainder theorem somehow to simplify into the information I was given, but I don't see how. How should I solve these problems?

Comment: Personally, I'd use [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion#Generalized_criterion) to show that $x^2+y^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb C[y][x]$ and in $\mathbb R[y][x]$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I don't think we've learned this criterion yet.. It sounds like the thing with which to prove $\mathbb F[x,y]/ \left\langle xy+b \right\rangle$ is an integral domain, but we may use this freely. Is there a way to avoid it and just use what we're given?

Comment: It can't be too hard to prove that $x^2 + y^2 + 1$ is irreducible. Just check that you can't write it as a product of factors of degree 1. In the case of $\mathbb{R}$ this is obvious because the polynomial has no zeros.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli sorry, I don't know what characteristics of fields are. Do you mean that $\mathbb F[x,y]/ \left\langle xy+b \right\rangle$ is not an integral domain for some values of this number?

Comment: @user298900 Sorry, I had deleted my comment. My perplexity was: in an *arbitrary* *field* $\mathbb F$, it is *true* that $\mathbb F[x,y]/\langle xy+b\rangle$ is a domain if and only if $b\ne 0$. However, in arbitrary fields it is *not* true that $\mathbb F[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2+1\rangle$ is a domain. There are fields (called of characteristic $2$) where $1+1=0$. In these fields it holds $$(x+y+1)^2=x^2+y^2+1$$ That's why I was skeptical on the use of that lemma. Jokes on me: I was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\mathbb C$, you can use the fact you stated by a change of variables: observe that $x^2+y^2+1 = (x+iy)(x-iy)+1$, and rewrite $\mathbb C[x,y]$ as $\mathbb C[w, z]$ with $w=x+iy$ and $z=x-iy$.

For $\mathbb R$, my guess is you are supposed to use the $\mathbb C$ case; show that the kernel of the homomorphism $\mathbb R[x,y] \to \mathbb C[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2+1\rangle$ given by $x \mapsto x$ and $y \mapsto y$ is precisely the ideal in $\mathbb R[x,y]$ generated by $x^2+y^2+1$. This will induce an embedding of $\mathbb R[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2+1\rangle$ into $\mathbb C[x,y]/\langle x^2+y^2+1\rangle$, witnessing that the former is an integral domain since the latter is.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was meant to do. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, now I see why they were given that hint!

Answer (score 1):

For any field $K$ of characteristic not equal to $2$, the polynomial $x^2+y^2+1$ is irreducible in $K[x,y]$ (a sketch of a proof of this claim is provided in the hidden section below, but the idea is to use Eisenstein's Criterion with $K[y][x]=K[x,y]$).  As $K[x,y]$ is a unique factorization domain, $x^2+y^2+1$ is also prime in $K[x,y]$, whence the ideal $\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)$ is a prime ideal.  Therefore, $K[x,y]/\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)$ is an integral domain.

> It remains to show that $x^2+y^2+1$ is irreducible over $K$.  This can be done by applying Eisenstein's Criterion to $x^2+y^2+1$, treating it as an element of $K[y][x]$.  Show that there is no irreducible element $p(y)\in K[y]$ such that $\left(p(y)\right)^2$ divides $y^2+1$ (this will be the reason why $K$ can't be of characteristic $2$).

---

If $K$ is of characteristic $2$, then $x^2+y^2+1=(x+y+1)^2$, so $K[x,y]/\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)$ has a nonzero nilpotent element, namely the image of $x+y+1$ under the quotient map $K[x,y]\to K[x,y]/\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)$.

---

**Question:** Prove that, if $K$ is a field of characteristic not equal to $3$, then $K[x,y]/\left(x^3+y^3+1\right)$ is an integral domain.

---

**Edit:** G. Sassatelli had already mentioned in the comment above what I did.

Comment: @user26857 That he didnt learn Eisenstein's criterion is not ground for using it in an answer on this website.  This is not an exam where you have to use only permitted materials to verify something.  Also, I posted this solution because it can be generalized in many ways.  That is why I asked a question about $x^3+y^3+1$.

Comment: *not ground for **prohibiting** using it ...