# Polynomial Ring Quotient of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ by $x^2 + y^2 -1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find a simpler ring that is isomorphic to this polynomial ring quotient: $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 -1)$.

I've tried to use the isomorphism theorem by defining $\phi$ a ring homomorphism so that I can show the quotient ring is isomorphic to $Im(\phi)/\ker(\phi)$. But I'm stuck and not sure if this is the right approach.

$\phi: \mathbb{R}[x,y] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]\diagup(x^2-1) \,\times\,\mathbb{R}[y]\diagup(y^2 -1) \,\,\,\,$ the ring homomorphism

$\phi\big(p(x,y)\big) := \big(p(x,0),p(0,y)\big) \in  \mathbb{R}[x]\times\mathbb{R}[y]\,\,\,\,$ with each entry mod its respective equation

where

- $\phi(0)=(0,0)$
- $\phi(1)=(1,1)$
- $\phi\big(p(x,y)q(x,y)\big)=\big(p(x,0)q(x,0),p(0,y)q(0,y)\big)=\big(p(x,0),p(0,y)\big)\big(q(x,0),q(0,y)\big)=\phi\big(p(x,y)\big)\phi\big(q(x,y)\big)$
- $\phi\big(p(x,y)+q(x,y)\big)=\big(p(x,0)+q(x,0),p(0,y)+q(0,y)\big)=\big(p(x,0),p(0,y)\big)+\big(q(x,0),q(0,y)\big)=\phi\big(p(x,y)\big)+\phi\big(q(x,y)\big)$

Now if $p(x,y)\in \ker\phi$ then

- $p(x,0) \mod (x^2 -1) = 0 \,\,\,\Longrightarrow \,\,\,p(\pm1,0)=0$
- $p(0,y) \mod (y^2 -1) = 0 \,\,\,\Longrightarrow \,\,\,p(0,\pm1)=0$

Would we then have:

$\mathbb{R}[x,y]\diagup\ker(\phi) \cong \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The polynomial $xy$ is in the kernel but not in the ideal generated by $x^2+y^2-1$.

Comment: The quotient ring is an integral domain, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576779/proving-mathbb-cx-y-langle-x2y21-rangle-mathbb-rx-y-langle-x2y2?rq=1). Note that $\Bbb R\times \cdots \times \Bbb R$ has zero divisors.

Comment: I wonder what you mean by computing a quotient ring? Anyway, not every quotient ring is isomorphic to some rings you previously know, and this is the case here.

Comment: @user26857 I want to find a simpler ring that’s isomorphic and easier to work with.

Comment: Bad luck! There is no such "simpler" ring.